# ElasticSearch - grouping by two different fields

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Is there a way to apply group by on two fields in elasticsearch??

```
TermsBuilder yearAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("by_year").field("year").subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("by_name")).field("Name").subAggregation(sumMarks);
            // create the bool filter for the condition above
            String[] names = { "stokes", "roshan" };
            BoolQueryBuilder aggFilter = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("Name", names));

            // create the filter aggregation and add the year sub-aggregation
            FilterAggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders.filter("agg").filter(aggFilter).subAggregation(yearAgg);

            // create the request and execute it
            SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("bighalf").setTypes("excel").addAggregation(aggregation).execute().actionGet();
            System.out.println(response.toString());
```

I tried to apply group by on two different terms but Am not getting the expected result.

Response after grouping:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "agg": {
      "doc_count": 2,
      "by_year": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "roshan",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "by_name": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": "roshan",
                  "doc_count": 1
                }
              ]
            },
            "sum_marks": {
              "value": 85
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "stokes",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "by_name": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": "stokes",
                  "doc_count": 1
                }
              ]
            },
            "sum_marks": {
              "value": 91
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I could only see the document count under "by_name" grouping. Is there a better way to apply grouping on two different fields in elasticsearch.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to solve. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Hi Val,

If u consider a SQL query it will look like this.

select year, name, SUM(grade), sum(marks) from table where datasquare_id='253991ba-e41e-4a3e-965e-d21900f92d4e' and marks> 60 group by year,name;


Here Am grouping by year and name as well as I could able to apply filters.

Using elasticsearch I could able to group by using "year" but I could group using both "year" and "Name".

Comment: Let me know if Am still not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in the way you build your aggregation, you're using the same field `Name` for both the `by_year` and `by_name` aggregation.

```
// your code
TermsBuilder yearAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("by_year")
    .field("year").subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("by_name")).field("Name").subAggregation(sumMarks);
                                                                      ^
                                                                      |
                                             This parenthesis is wrong, it should go at the end
```

Do it like this instead

```
TermsBuilder yearAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("by_year").field("year")
    .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("by_name").field("Name").subAggregation(sumMarks));
```

Comment: Oh great. I understood how it works. Thanks a lot Val.